# plone two adapters providing ISchemaExtender

Tags: schema, plone

I am trying to use two plone addon products both using archetypes.schemaextender.

Since both products have to be explicit in which interface the adapters provide, they have

```
provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender"
```

in their zcml, which gives the following conflict:

```
raise ConfigurationConflictError(conflicts)
zope.configuration.config.ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions
  For: ('adapter', (<InterfaceClass Products.ATContentTypes.interfaces.document.IATDocument>,), <InterfaceClass archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender>, '')
    File "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/src/collective.guestbookcomments/collective/guestbookcomments/configure.zcml", line 14.2-15.69
        <adapter factory=".guestbookcomments.PageExtender" 
           provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender"/>
    File "/usr/local/Plone4/zeocluster/src/kuehnel.naturfreundeskreis/kuehnel/naturfreundeskreis/configure.zcml", line 54.2-55.69
        <adapter factory=".topimagefield.PageExtender"
           provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender"/>
```

Is it possible for two products to extend a document by archetypes.schemaextender?

This is on Plone 4.3.2 via unified installer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is, you have to register named adapters.

Example:

```xml
<include package="archetypes.schemaextender" />

<adapter factory=".factory.Factory"
     provides="archetypes.schemaextender.interfaces.ISchemaExtender"
     name="my.extender.name" />
```